# How do I increment a certain index of a list?

Tags: list, f#, iteration

here's my code: (should work fine)

```
let rec interleave = function
    | ([],ys) -> []
    | (xs,[]) -> []
    | (x::xs,y::ys) -> x :: y :: interleave (xs, ys)

let gencut n list = 
    let first = list |> Seq.take n |> Seq.toList
    let last = list |> Seq.skip n |> Seq.toList
    (first, last)


let cut list = gencut ((List.length list)/2) list

let shuffle x = interleave (cut x)

let isNotSame (list1, list2) = if list1 = list2 then false else true

let countShuffles xs =
    let mutable newList = xs
    let mutable x = 1
    if (List.length(xs) > 1) then newList <- shuffle newList
    while isNotSame (newList, xs) do
        newList <- shuffle newList
        x <- x + 1
    x 

//lists countShuffles from 1 to x
let listShuffles x =
    for i = 1 to x/2 do
        let y = [1..(i*2)]
        let z = countShuffles y
        printf "A deck of %d cards takes %d shuffles\n" (i*2) z
    printf ""
```

The flow is (from main function down to 1st helper):
listShuffles -> countShuffles -> shuffle + isNotSame -> cut -> gencut + interleave
(so just try listShuffles)

What "countShuffles" does is:
take an int, creates a list, (1..n), (which is supposed to represent a deck of cards),
cuts it in half, does a perfect-out shuffle (perfect bridge shuffle)
and counts how many shuffles it takes to make the deck original again

What listShuffles does is:
takes an int, and prints out countShuffles 1 through n

(you need an even amount of cards in the deck)

Sorry about the explanation, now my question:

is it possible to see how many times a certain number is returned?
i.e.:
listShuffles 10000;;
see how many times "16" appeared.

i was thinking of making a list.

and incrementing a given index.

which represents a certain number that was returned.

but i cant find how to do that...

p.s. i dont care how my code is wrong or anything like that,

this is my first F# program, and it is homework based on my professor's criteria,

(the assignment is complete, this question is for curiosity)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few alternatives

If you only want one number you can do

```
List |> Seq.sumBy (fun t -> if t = 16 then 1 else 0)
```

If you want a range of different numbers, it may be better to do

```
let map = List |> Seq.countBy (fun t -> t) |> Map.ofSeq
```

then `map.[16]` is the number of times that `16` occurs in the list

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
let listShuffles x =
    [| for i = 1 to x/2 do
        yield countShuffles [1..(i*2)] |]
```

Now this function return array and then you can use Array module functions to find how many times a number appears

```
listShuffles 1000 |> Array.filter ((=) 16) |> Array.length
```

Or to print all such numbers and their occurrence count:

```
listShuffles 100
|> Array.toSeq |> Seq.groupBy id
|> Seq.iter (fun (k,v) -> printfn "%d appears %d times" k (v.Count()))
```